# show the negative of distinct cases

Tags: r, distinct

How can I check that the *distinct* argument has removed only the cases I wanted?

I have this toy data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

ID = as.integer(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
Program = c("P1", "P2", "P2", "P1", "P2")
From = as.Date(c("2016-10-01", "2016-07-01", "2016-01-25", "2016-05-01", "2016-04-06")) 
To = as.Date(c("2017-03-31", "2016-11-27", "2016-06-30", "2016-06-02", "2016-04-23")) 
df = tibble(ID, Program, From, To)
df
```

where I want to retain only the last instance of participation in the same programme. It should look like this:

```
df2 = distinct(df, ID, Program, .keep_all = TRUE)
df2
```

This works fine, but my original data frame has 100 000 cases, and I want to find a way how to verify that I did not remove someone who I should have kept in.

I tried *unique* and *duplicated* arguments, but can only use them on single variables; not to subset the whole data frame on them. I can randomly pick some cases like this:

```
df2[df2$ID == 2,]
```

but there must be a more systematic approach.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with using `!duplicated(df[, 1:2])` to index the `df`? it seems to keep the rows you want to keep.

Comment: what verification do you have in mind? you can use `unique(bind_cols(ID = df$ID, Program =df$Program))` to see if your `distinct` approach has the same outcome. you can do a `merge` or `anti_join` if you have large lists.

Comment: Your current solution depends on the order of rows in the data frame, which happens to have `To` dates in descending order. This makes your use of `distinct` work as intended. Otherwise I'm not sure what the problem is. Are you worried about bugs in these functions that might cause errors?

Comment: I was triyng to use "-" in front of the indexed variables, and forgot the "!duplicated" argument. So simple! Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer only works if your data frame is in a certain order (specifically, decreasing order of `To` within each `ID` and `Program` group.)

Since you're in the tidyverse anyway, here's another way to do it, which avoids having to have the data frame in any particular order.

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Program) %>% filter(To == max(To))
```

To see what I mean about order mattering, try running this code and your code on `df[sample(nrow(df)),]` and notice that this code always outputs the same rows (although not in the same order) while your code does not. In principle you could pre-sort the data frame, but that is overkill for the problem you're trying to solve which is just to find the largest date for each `ID` and `Program` combination.

As far as verification goes, unless there is a bug in any of these very commonly used functions, I'm not sure what you're concerned about.

Comment: Very elegant, thank you. I see your point. I extended your code like this: `...filter(To == max(To) | is.na(To))` and run it on my original df. The difference between the result of the code suggested by you and the one suggested by Rui Barradas is 40 cases. Do you have any clue what might cause this difference?

Comment: Other than your data not being in the order you think it is or should be I couldn't guess what is causing the difference. Try running the codes on `df_sorted <- df %>% group_by(ID, Program) %>% arrange(desc(To))` and see if the results are the same.  Also note that if the `To` column is allowed to have ties, my code will return both rows if that tied date is the maximum.. You can check that with `any(duplicated(df2))` where `df2` is the output as per your naming convention. Note that it would be better to use `To == max(To, na.rm = TRUE)` than your (correct) change to the code I suggested.

Comment: There were some ties but less than the difference between the result of two solutions. I will have to thing about that, and also order the df before doing anything with it. Thank you very much for your help!